# tikz 3d graph with circular domain

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, 3d

I have got a pretty simple function to make a 3D graph of. The function is defined as:

[image: forumula]

Plotting this was not that much of a problem with the follwing code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.8,
  colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white); color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    colormap name=whitered,
    3d box,
    width=15cm,
    view={25}{25},
    enlargelimits=false,
    grid=major,
    domain=-2:6,
    y domain=1:9,
    zmin=0,zmax=7,
    samples=21,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        at={(1,0)},
        anchor=south west,
        height=0.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height}
        }
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf]
      {sqrt((x-2)^2+(y-5)^2)};

    \addplot3 [contour gnuplot = {number=14, labels={false},
      draw color = black}, samples = 21, ]
      {sqrt((x-2)^2+(y-5)^2)};

    \addplot3 [contour gnuplot = {number=14, labels={false}, draw color=black},
        samples=21,z filter/.code={\def\pgfmathresult{20}}]
        {sqrt((x-2)^2+(y-5)^2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:
[image: plot]

Now to my problem: My domain is defined circular as following:

[image: domain]

Is there any possibility limiting the plot to the given domain? Do I need to go for a completely different approach like another coordinate system than the Cartesian or something like that?

Comment: I have no time to dig this out, but --- see if http://riotorto.users.sourceforge.net/gnuplot/func3d/index.html (scroll down to "plot an explicit function or parametric surface when its domain is not a rectangle") can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial solution (I skipped the contour level plots to simplify, let that as an exercise for the braves):

Using the three-way if `(boolean)?(value if true):(value if false)` and the special "number" `NaN` (not-a-number), and using the option `unbounded coords=jump`  you can do the following:

```
\addplot3 [surf, unbounded coords=jump]
    { (x-2)^2+(y-5)^2<9 ? sqrt((x-2)^2+(y-5)^2) : NaN };
```

You have

[image: Output]

with your bound -- `(x-1)^2+y^2<9` (which is not centered with respect to the center of the ellipsoid) it is a bit strange:

[image: Other output]

...but I think it's ok note it changed the `x` and `y` scales, if you fix them:

[image: again, forced scales]

Comment: That NaN was what I was looking for thank you so much :)

Comment: Notice that `unbounded coords=jump` is necessary here --- otherwise strange things will happen.

Comment: Oh ok. Good to know. Currently I am at University but as soon as I get home I will try it