# How can I make a 3D representation of a potential well

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I want to do draw a 3D representation of a potential well in cartesain coordinates, like this:

[image: 3D representation of a potential well]

Since I never had to do 3D plots, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Try starting here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307724/tikz-3d-graph-with-circular-domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.8,
  colormap={whitered}{color(0cm)=(white); color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    colormap name=whitered,
    3d box,
    width=15cm,
    view={25}{25},
    enlargelimits=false,
    grid=major,
    domain=-5:5,
    y domain=-5:5,
    zmin=-1,zmax=1,
    samples=51,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf, unbounded coords=jump]
        { -exp(-(x*x+y*y)/2) };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: gaussian well]

and if you add

```
\node at (axis cs: 1,1,0) [blue, circle, shading=ball]{};
```

you can have:

[image: with a small ball...]